# Where do I find the appropriate image to use when I want to spin up a Ubuntu instance in an openstack cloud?

Tags: image, cloud, openstack

I'd like to spin up an instance in Openstack. I want that instance running Ubuntu.

Looking at http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/ I expect to find something with either the .qcow2 or .iso extension but I can find neither in http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/bionic/current/ (for example)

Can someone please explain where I can find an image that, when uploaded to an Openstack cloud, can be used to create an instance running Ubuntu?

ANSWER: .img = qcow2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes I got from the Openstack document may help you: https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/obtain-images.html

> Ubuntu¶
>
> Canonical maintains an official set of Ubuntu-based images.
>
> Images are arranged by Ubuntu release, and by image release date, with current being  the most recent. For example, the page that contains the most recently built image for Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) Daily Build. Scroll to the bottom of the page for links to the images that can be downloaded directly.
>
> If your deployment uses QEMU or KVM, we recommend using the images in qcow2 format. The most recent version of the 64-bit QCOW2 image for Ubuntu 16.04 is xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img.

Comment: Ah OK so the answer is that .img here are actually .qcow2 ...... fantastic........